# Need help cracking a MacOS Catalina password

Tags: password-cracking, macos, hashcat

I have found the hashes for the stored passwords on my mac, I do not have the administrator passwords, I do have the hashes coming from the /var folder. I have tried decrypting it using hashcat but it keeps failing due to multiple errors that I don't really know how to fix..

`Hash '?d?d?d?d': Token length exception`
I was just doing a test with another hash and it was kinda not working...

`Hash 'hash.txt': Signature unmatched No hashes loaded.`

```
=======================
* Device #1: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics, skipped

OpenCL API (OpenCL 1.2 (Aug 11 2021 00:46:43)) - Platform #1 [Apple]
====================================================================
* Device #2: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1000NG4 CPU @ 1.10GHz, 4064/8192 MB (1024 MB allocatable), 4MCU
* Device #3: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics, skipped

Minimum password length supported by kernel: 0
Maximum password length supported by kernel: 256

Hash 'hash.txt': Signature unmatched
No hashes loaded.

Started: Wed Apr 13 07:33:34 2022
Stopped: Wed Apr 13 07:33:34 2022
```

And many more errors, please help me, I really don't know what to do. I really need to crack the password, it is only 8 caracters. Also if someone is ready to help me crack it or can do it for me, I would be more than happy, it's not a very confidential password :), write to me in DM's and I will really be happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the command you are trying? It looks like you might be specifying the hash in the wrong place, or the wrong hash type. Also, unless you know part of the password, you may not be able to crack the hash without dedicated hardware.

Comment: This is the comment I used : /Users/[user]/Desktop/hashcat/hashcat/hashcat -m 7100 hash.txt -a 3 "?d?d?d?s?d?u?u?u"

Comment: I know that it ends with 3 caps letters well 99% chance, and it starts with mostly numbers mixed with symbols

Comment: Have you tried supplying the hash directly in the command-line? `hashcat -m 7100 -a 3 {insert hash} "?d?d?d?s?d?u?u?u"` works for me.

Comment: As a side note, the hash you posted earlier is still accessible in the post's edit history. You might want to flag for moderator attention and request its redaction.

Comment: I don't mind lol

Comment: I put the hash with {} surrounding it? I will try tonight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135538/discussion-between-adeveloper-and-nobody).